# Replacing Blade with Twig in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, twig, laravel-blade

I am attempting to swap out Laravel's native Blade Templating for Symfony's [Twig Templating Engine](https://twig.symfony.com). However during the composer require of [twigbridge](https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge) I get the following errors :

```
Using version ^0.9.5 for rcrowe/twigbridge
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[1.x-dev, v2.4.4].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.4, 1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[1.x-dev, v2.4.4].
    - rcrowe/twigbridge v0.9.5 requires twig/twig ~1.30 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[1.x-dev].
    - Installation request for rcrowe/twigbridge ^0.9.5 -> satisfiable by rcrowe/twigbridge[v0.9.5].
    - Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v2.4.4, required as ^2.4) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v2.4.4].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

I may be misinterpreting the errors, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to update `rcrowe/twigbridge` to a newer version that is compatible with twig version 2.4.4, or downgrade twig so that it is compatible with `rcrowe/twigbridge v0.9.5`.

`rcrowe/twigbridge` has listed in it's composer.json requirements:

```
"twig/twig": "~1.30",
```

**edit**

I looks like 0.9.5 is that latest version of `rcrowe/twigbridge` so your only option is using an older version of `twig/twig`

Comment: i figured the was the case... eh, twig v1 isn't as robust as 2. i think ill just stick to blade. im using react on the front anyway, so i won't be writing to much blade

Comment: Blade is solid templating system, imo. It has some nice features to it with the builtin directives. If you're building an SPA it really doesn't matter as much which templating engine you use.